# How does alcohol increase firing rate in Golgi cells?

Tags: brain, alcohol

I understood that ethanol increases Golgi cell firing by inhibiting the Na+/K+ ATPase channels, which makes granule cells receive more GABAergic input from the GABA that Golgi cells relase.
Some paragraph in this [paper](http://www.nature.com/npp/journal/v35/n9/full/npp201076a.html?foxtrotcallback=true) are not clear to me. It says that

> *ethanol increased spontaneous firing frequency and depolarized the membrane potential in the perforated-patch configuration*, but also that *ethanol does not significantly affect firing frequency or membrane potential response to current injection*.

How does it work?